# Post php qr color code values not working with form

Tags: php, forms, qr-code

I am trying to generate a colored QR Code using [phpqrcode](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode).

if I directly give the value to fore and background color it works fine. when I am trying to post the values it does not work.

My Code :

```
$textname = $_POST["text"];
$filename = $_POST["filename"];
$level = $_POST["level"];
$size = $_POST["size"];
$margin = $_POST["margin"];
$backcolor = $_POST["backcolor"];
$forecolor = $_POST["forecolor"];
QRcode::png($textname , $filename, $level, $size, $margin, false,  $backcolor, $forecolor);
```

works very fine:

```
 $backcolor = 0xFFFFFF;
 $forecolor = 0x00000;
```

not works:

```
$backcolor = $_POST["backcolor"];
$forecolor = $_POST["forecolor"];
```

Comment: try using the inspector and see what postvars are passing.

Comment: @RobertSaylor that's everything fine. I think it's because of string conversion. but I don't know to convert that string to hex

Comment: maybe it is getting encoded. You could try urldecode. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @RobertSaylor Thanks for the solution but still the same. the direct hex values working very well only passing the values in trouble. the form also working very well. I tested the input values it's fine.

Comment: I would suggest to switch to a new (maintained) library accepting simple Hex-Codes as String. As this software is not maintained almost since 11/2016... (Alternatives: https://packagist.org/?query=qrcode)

If you have to use it, can you provide var_dump output for your manual values and the POST values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the color code to Hexadecimal value. Replace your code as below

```
$backcolor = hexdec(str_replace('#','0x',$_POST["backcolor"]);

$forecolor = hexdec(str_replace('#','0x',$_POST["forecolor"]);
```